# 421 Misdirected Request error when loading my myurl that redirects to subdomain m.myurl

Tags: ssl, redirect, mobile-devices

When refreshing, it eventually loads.

The background is,
I have a main domain, and two subdomains,  blog.myurl and m.myurl
The blog. is hosting blogger page with its own SSL
The main domain and the m.myurl were using the same SSL

When opening my URL in any mobile browser, it will initially give the misdirected request notice before loading the site. (chrome, safari, firefox all tested and same issue.   Once the site loads, occasionally when clicking between the pages, I will also experience the misdirect notice(which are all main domain links in bootsrap navbar with the main site pages redirecting to mobile based on screen width) It seems to especially happen when clicking through to the blog, the blog always loads fine, and then when clicking any link in the navbar from the blog, the misdirect notice will happen.

Based on research that led me here, [421 Misdirected Request](https://serverfault.com/questions/916724/421-misdirected-request) , I decided to use a different SSL token for the m. subdomain to see if that solved the problem.  I also called Godaddy support, and the rep said he couldn't recreate the problem on his end (seemed to be loading fine on his phone) and told me to wait 48 hours and see if I still have the problem. I've tried from several devices, and all mobile browsers are experiencing the issue.

Could this be a problem with how I am doing the mobile redirect? Should I post the code for it?
The redirect works. When clicking mysite URL links from a phone they auto redirect to mobile subdomain properly like I want them to. It just seems that I am getting this error and I think its SSL based, but now I am not sure since changing SSL didn't fix it.

Comment: What is your domain name? What is the web server configuration?

Comment: ramycapital.ca
m.ramycapital.ca
blog.ramycapital.ca

There is some pages that link from both m. and the main URL , suchas ramycapital.ca/forum and ramycapital.ca/newsletter  and blog.ramycapital.ca .  Clicking in between any of these and other site links produces many misdirect error notices
Web Server Configuration is Cpanel Linux

Comment: would turning off http2 fix my problem? Is it a bad idea? Can I even do that with cpanel?

Comment: It's cPanel so we have no idea. We don't accept cPanel questions here.

Comment: Moving m subdomain to a different SSL certificate did in fact solve my problem, once I properly removed subdomains from the other SSL.